# Convert T-SQL into LINQ Lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, lambda

How can i write this query in LINQ lambda expression or query syntax if required? I have been trying for a while now. The multiple joins are making it difficult. The total records on the join are over 2000 and the final result should be about 15 records

```
select 
    year([date]), 
    month([date]),
    sum(ot.rate)
from s as s 
join cs cs on cs.s_id= s.id
join ot ot on ot.id = cs.o_id
group by
    year([date]), 
    month([date])
```

this is the closest I have got but will not compile. I cannot access the ot property from within the select block.

```
    var query = from se in table_se
        join cs in table_cs on se.Id equals cs.S_Id
        join ot in table_ot on cs.O_Id equals ot.Id
        group se by new { se.Date.Year, se.Date.Month } into grp 
        select new
        {
            grp.Key.Year,
            grp.Key.Month,
            grp.Sum(ot.Rate)
        };
```

Comment: Install Resharper and it will do your job :)

Comment: If you've been "trying for a while now" then presumably you should be able to tell us what you've tried, and what went wrong. It may be that what other people would suggest is something you've already tried...

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated with the closest I have been able to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close - [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx) takes a predicate

```
var query = from se in table_se
        join cs in table_cs on se.Id equals cs.S_Id
        join ot in table_ot on cs.O_Id equals ot.Id
        group ot by new { se.Date.Year, se.Date.Month } into grp 
        select new
        {
            Year = grp.Key.Year,
            Month = grp.Key.Month,
            Sum = grp.Sum(x => x.Rate)
        };
```

Comment: when i try that the x property is 'se' and not 'ot' which is where the Rate field is

Comment: Ok. need to change 'group se by new' into 'group ot by new'

Comment: @Grant - ah yes, I see that now. Good update. Glad you got the solution :)